# In Swift, given a variable that is an enum, how can I tell which case it is?

Tags: swift, enums

As a practical example, suppose I define:

```
enum Baby {
    case Boy (String)
    case Girl (String)
}
```

and then define a variable (or constant) like so:

> let baby1 = Baby.Boy("Joe")

Now I want to pass baby1 to a function that returns a string that depends on whether baby1 is a boy or a girl. How do I write that function? Or is there no way to do that?

Comment: After writing this I realize that my little example over simplifies the actual question. I know how to answer the question as written so don't bother responding. But I still don't know how to write the function I really want to write. I'll have to think about how to explain the question better before asking again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you said not to answer, but this might help:

Using a `switch` statement, you can simultaneously detect the case of the enum and extract the `String` for use:

```
enum Baby {
    case Boy (String)
    case Girl (String)
}

let baby1 = Baby.Boy("Joe")
let baby2 = Baby.Girl("Sue")

func babyDescription(baby: Baby) -> String {
    switch(baby) {
    case .Boy(let name):
        return "A baby boy named \(name)"
    case .Girl(let name):
        return "A baby girl named \(name)"
    }
}

println(babyDescription(baby1)) // "A baby boy named Joe"
println(babyDescription(baby2)) // "A baby girl named Sue"
```